# Query SQS based on a custom MessageAttribute

Tags: amazon-sqs

So SQS has MessageAttributes that you can attach to jobs, letting you store metadata on jobs.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/simple-queue-service-message-attributes/

Is there a way to query a queue based on one of these attributes?

**Example:** I want to set a "Tag" MessageAttribute, and then query the queue to see how many jobs with a "Tag" of "something" exist.

Comment: Hi did you find a way?

Comment: @VAAA No. I've sinced moved jobs and haven't worked with SQS since, but there ended up being no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The best option would be to read all the messages and then delete only those which match your criteria. All the other messages that you have read will show up back in the queue after the visibility timeout.

Comment: Heh, yeah that won't work with a queue that has 100k+ jobs in it, and ReceiveMessages only pulling 10 at a time. Bummer.

Comment: @JonUrsenbach what do you recommend me then?

Comment: @VAAA I don't know, honestly. It's been a few years since I've used SQS and I don't remember what I ended up doing instead.